# Weather will (go bad/deteriorate/spoil or...)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Please suppose you're going to take a travel in your car for a long distance tomorrow and you are worried if you will have a bad weather tomorrow. (Today you're having a nice weather). I was wondering which choice sounds natural or more natural in my following sentence in and in this sense:

> - I hope the weather will not................tomorrow.

a) deteriorate 
b) go bad 
c) spoil

If there is a better choice, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two verbs most often used in this respect are **deteriorate** (as you surmise) and **worsen**. **Go bad** and **spoil** are not idiomatic.

Your question is badly phrased; we never talk about **a** weather, just **weather** or **the weather**. It should have read:

**Please suppose you're going to travel in your car for a long distance tomorrow and you are worried THAT you will have bad weather. (Today you're having nice weather). I was wondering which choice sounds natural or more natural in THE following sentence:**

And you could further improve it by shortening it to:

**Suppose you're going to travel a long distance in your car tomorrow and you are worried about running into bad weather.....**

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, don't think it sounds idiomatic to say that the weather will "deteriorate", although certain conditions related to weather, such as "visibility", may do so.

> Over the next hour the fog got thicker and visibility **deteriorated**, until they could barely see a dozen feet in front of the car and could only move forward at a virtual crawl.

We do not use "go bad" or "spoil" with weather.  Both of those imply more when food becomes *rotten, sour*, or *moldy*.

"Worsen", on the other hand, is fine when talking about the weather.  I prefer "get worse", but that's just my writing style.  I would also say that the weather *is* worse rather than *gets* worse:

> I hope the weather **isn't worse** tomorrow.

Or just that it's not poor weather:

> I hope we don't **have bad weather** tomorrow.

Comment: Is it a matter of personal preference @Andrew? I'm about using the verb "deteriorate".

Comment: @A-friend  Yeah, looks like it.  I see a good number of instances on Ngram.